# How can I connect Domo data tables to R Studio?

Tags: r, api, export, connector, domo

I am trying to connect directly to a Domo data set within my datawarehouse in Domo. Is there a way I could make a direct connection to the Domo dataset in R? I simply want to have a connection directly to the dataset so as to avoid having to download a CSV and then import manually.

Comment: This might help : https://github.com/domoinc-r/DomoR

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. When I run these two lines:

library("devtools")
install_github(repo="domoinc-r/DomoR")

I receive the following error:

Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = h) : 
  Could not resolve host: api.github.com

I believe it is because of my corporate proxy settings, could you please help with this as well?

Comment: Not sure to be honest, and it seems there are a few people who have had similar problems, but not always cause by the same issue, like here : https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1915 and here https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1996, you might have to do some googling about that, you should however first try installing the package from the filesystem (like described by the developers in the README)